# join.str() is giving Nan values

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

when i am trying to join str with ' ' sep, i am getting Nan values. Below is the code and output.

df_groupby_company_10.ID
company
(dah)bryan Isd                              [100645170, 102320579, 102565211, 102797936]
1-800-Flowers.com, Inc.                     [100054859, 100066805, 100224589, 100497986]
1199seiu United Health Care Workers East    [100123809, 100392880, 100512699, 103499749]
1st Source Corporation                      [100345458, 100349515, 100472860, 100519219]
2020 Company, LLC                           [100213385, 100245719, 100248099, 100333687]
21st Century Insurance Company              [100036144, 100258483, 100264759, 100405599]

df_groupby_company_10['ID'].str.join(' ')
company
(dah)bryan Isd                             NaN
1-800-Flowers.com, Inc.                    NaN
1199seiu United Health Care Workers East   NaN
1st Source Corporation                     NaN
2020 Company, LLC                          NaN
21st Century Insurance Company             NaN

but it should give result like for ID column:
103730851 122564134 137669806 138117993
115079368 117608628 118146856 123930476

could anyone tell me what wrong i am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in lists are integers, is necessary convert them to strings:

```
df_groupby_company_10['ID'].apply(lambda x: [str(y) for y in x]).str.join(' ')
```

Or:

```
df_groupby_company_10['ID'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(str(y) for y in x))
```

Comment: @PavanChauhan - Because integers, in pandas if some wrong type like here error is not rased, but returned `NaN`

Comment: Yep, that was my case here as well. Ended up converting the entire column astype(str)